# XPath query to select nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmlnodelist

I have the following XML:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Persons>
      <Person>
        <PersonID>6352</PersonID>
        <Forename>Tristan</Forename>
      </Person>
      <Person>
        <PersonID>6353</PersonID>
        <Forename>Ruth</Forename>
      </Person>
      <Person>
        <PersonID>6913</PersonID>
        <Forename>Mina</Forename>
        <Surname>Asif</Surname>
      </Person>
      <Person>
        <PersonID>6914</PersonID>
        <Forename>Clark</Forename>
        <Surname>Williams</Surname>
      </Person>
    </Persons>
```

I use the following code to load the xml:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(@"example.xml");
```

I need to ask for all nodes that DO NOT have a Surname using an XPath query and the select nodes call (something similar to the following pseudo):

```
XmlNodeList nodes1 = xDoc.SelectNodes("//Person[Surname=null]");
```

I'm pretty new to XPath, any pointers much appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620469/xslt-xpath-test-for-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following XPath :

```
//Person[not(Surname)]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! :-)  I used this to select just PersonID from the result: "//Person[(AdmissionNumber)]/PersonID".  Thanks!!